# Without coupon = Shipping free, with coupon = with shipping - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help for my WooCommerce Shop. 
Our customers get free shipping after a amount of 39€. 
If our customers get a price under 39€ after using a coupon, shipping is no more free.

So for example:

Customers is on Cart, full cart amount is 42€ = Shipping Free.

Use -15% off Coupon = cart amount is 38,55 = Shipping costs <- but this still have to be free

In the plugin i use, i can set the setting "allow shipping free" but then the customer gets shipping free after the minimum amount for the coupon so this isnt usefull for us.

I use the Plugin = WooCommerce Extended Coupon Features FREE
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-added-coupons/

Hope you guys understand what I mean

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a simple code snippet.

you need to config one **Free shipping** without any **Minimum order amount** and a **Flat rate** to display normal shipping.

Now copy and paste below snippet into functions.php. It will hide free shipping if the subtotal less than 39, otherwise hide flat rate

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates',  'modify_shipping_rate', 15, 2 );
function modify_shipping_rate( $available_shipping_methods, $package ){

    global $woocmmerce;
    $total_coast = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();

    if( $total_coast < 39 ){
        unset($available_shipping_methods['free_shipping:4']); // Config the Free Shipping method id properly
    }else{
        unset($available_shipping_methods['flat_rate:1']); //// Config the Flatrate shipping method id properly
    }

    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```